# Undefine Input Value on function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, input

I'm completely new on this, but I'm trying to make a shopping cart with javaScript.
Everything were fine till I tried to add an input value to the items added to the cart.
I have an image, a price and a name, but I need to add a "QTY" field.

this is the input of that field:

```html
            
<input type="number" id="store-item-qty" type="qty" placeholder="QTY" name="text_name" class="store-item-qty">
```

and this is my script

```js
//value of qty---->
let qty =
       event.target.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.children[0].children[2].value;
   //add items to cart--->    
 cartItem.innerHTML = ` 
            <img src="${item.img}" class="img-fluid" id="item-img" alt="">
            <div class="item-text">

              <p id="cart-item-title" class="font-weight-bold mb-0">${item.name}</p>
              <p>    </p>
              <span id="cart-item-girth" class="cart-item-girth" class="mb-0">${item.girth}</span>
            </div>
            <p class="store-item-qty" type="qty" id="store-item-qty">${item.qty}</p>
            <a href="#" id='cart-item-remove' class="cart-item-remove">
              <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          `;
          
//var qty--->
var qty = "qty";
document.getElementById("store-item-qty").value;
```

But when I click "add to cart" it works importing the info of everything except the QTY field and says just "Undefine"

Comment: Please create a proper [mre].

Comment: You are using *let* and *var* with the same variable name, this will probably lead you into some issues. I recommend checking that

Comment: Ok let me upload the minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you get the value of Element `quantitiy` and define it like `let qty = ...`.
And in your template you try to read `qty` from `${item.qty}`.

Should read `${qty}` AFAIK.

Comment: Now it shows like "[Object HTMLInputElement]" instead of "Undefined", I guess is almost there but I'm missing something (sorry Is a suuuper new language for me haha)

Comment: Add `console.log(qty)` after getting the value. What is the result?

Comment: It shows: <input type="text" id="store-item-qty" placeholder="QTY" name="text_name" class="store-item-qty"> .... I guess is correct, but I need to define the value??

Comment: So you got the Input-Element. You just need to read out the value of the Element. Change `${qty}` to `${qty.value}`.

Comment: It worked!!! OMG I'm so happy, thank you! I just add .value after let qty=..... and it worked!!